# How to return average data through the loop in mysqli and php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a beginner programmer, and i want to fetch AVG() data in every rows created by the while loop,
this is the code,

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT sites_id, sites_nama, sites_alamat, sites_kota_kabupaten, perpanjangan_pagu, sites_tanggal_start, sites_tanggal_finish, perpanjangan_invoice, AVG(perpanjangan_pagu) FROM site";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
                        <th>Site ID</th>
                        <th>Site Name</th>
                        <th>Alamat</th>
                        <th>Kab.Kota</th>
                        <th>Pagu</th>
                        <th>Harga Rata Rata</th>
                        <th>Awal Kontrak</th>
                        <th>Akhir Kontrak</th>
                        <th>Invoice</th>
        </tr>";
    // output data of each row
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows = $row["AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)"];
        echo "
            <tr>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_id"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_nama"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_alamat"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_kota_kabupaten"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["perpanjangan_pagu"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $rows . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_tanggal_start"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_tanggal_finish"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["perpanjangan_invoice"] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    //echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

and this is the image, you can see that it only return one row.

[image: the first pic]

and this is the image when I deleted the avg function.

[image: the second image]

please help me to fetch the average data in every row in the table, not just only one table,

Thanks.

Comment: Use a `$rows[] = $row["AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)"];` instead of  `$rows = $row["AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)"];`
You can check by using `print_r($rows);` outside the loop.

Comment: but what if i want to print it inside the rows created by the loop?
as you can see, when i deleted the AVG function, they can print the whole rows properly, but when i use the AVG, they only show one row

Comment: I think `$row["AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)"]` this is simply a value, so you can use this directly in `<td>`

Comment: yes, but it still the same, it only return one row, not the whole 3 rows,
i need to fetch the AVG data in all the rows created by the loop

Comment: ok, so you have 3 records on DB & you are get only one when you use `AVG()`

Comment: TRy by changing query by replacing `AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)` into `(SELECT AVG(perpanjangan_pagu) FROM site) AS AVG_pagu`. And use `AVG_pagu` on listing section

Comment: No need to use `$rows = $row["AVG(perpanjangan_pagu)"];`. Use `$row['AVG_pagu'];` here you will get the average

Comment: so, how can i insert the AVG_pagu into the while loops?
because if we track to the first if, it only process the $sql,
or can you give me the example @Sinto?
Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this I have modified user code & added the AVG() column.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT sites_id, sites_nama, sites_alamat, sites_kota_kabupaten, perpanjangan_pagu, sites_tanggal_start, sites_tanggal_finish, perpanjangan_invoice, (SELECT AVG(perpanjangan_pagu) FROM site) AS 'AVG_pagu' FROM site";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//  AVG_pagu has the AVG value of all columns of `perpanjangan_pagu` in table `site`
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
                        <th>Site ID</th>
                        <th>Site Name</th>
                        <th>Alamat</th>
                        <th>Kab.Kota</th>
                        <th>Pagu</th>
                        <th>Harga Rata Rata</th>
                        <th>Awal Kontrak</th>
                        <th>Akhir Kontrak</th>
                        <th>Invoice</th>
        </tr>";
    //  output data of each row
    //  $rows = array(); // This is not actually required
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //$rows[] = $row["AVG_pagu"]; // This is not actually required
        echo "
            <tr>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_id"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_nama"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_alamat"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_kota_kabupaten"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["perpanjangan_pagu"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["AVG_pagu"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_tanggal_start"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["sites_tanggal_finish"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["perpanjangan_invoice"] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "No records found!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: your are always welcome to Ask Questions here... :-)